# How to get byte array from a JTextArea?

Tags: java, arrays, jtextarea

For my encryption software, I have to decrypt the contents of a `JTextArea` when the decryption button is pressed.

How do I get a `byte[]` containing the contents of my text area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your limited description, it sounds like you want to retrieve text from a `JTextArea` in the form of bytes.

This is straight-forward enough:

```
byte[] data = yourTextArea.getText().getBytes("charset-name");
```

Replace `"charset-name"` with your preferred character set.

Comment: i tried this one, but the result in byte[] data is different then the byte form entered in jtextarea.. for example, i enter "[B@1275595" in the jtextarea, the result in byte[] data = [B@1246532, it's been changed.. i need to be the same without any changes..

Comment: @user3077162 You must be printing the result of calling `toString()` on a byte array, which is not the way to inspect the contents. Try printing the result of `Arrays.toString(yourByteArray)`.

Comment: in my program, i encrypt a text entered in a jtextarea, then the result encrypted (converted from byte to string, to be showed in another jtextarea) is copied to be entered in another jtextarea for the decryption(the copied text is the encrypted one)... so i think the problem in my code is the convertion from byte to string ..

Comment: @user3077162 I believe I have answered your original question. If you have a new question, please ask it in a separate post.

Answer (score 0):

If your encrypted data starts with "[B@" it means that you are using ".toString()" in your code and it isnt the real encrypted data. To prove it, print the length too and you will see that its a lot longer. If you want the encrypted data do a for loop like this:

```
byte[] encryptedText=encrypt("Hello");

for(int i=0;i<encryptedText.length();i++) {
String s=String.valueOf(encryptedText[i]);
System.out.print(s);
}
```

Comment: Please don't use taglines in your answers. You're fine to link to your website from your profile, but we like to keep answers focused on only the relevant content.